# Ajax loading .txt not working

Tags: jquery, get

I'm simply trying to display the contents of a file retrieved by "$.get" but I'm not getting any results from the alert in the `get` . . Actually, the alarm in the `get` isn't even going off.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    $.ajax({ url:"tex.txt", complete:function(r){

        alert([
            'Response Status code: ' + r.status,
            "Response Text length: " + r.responseText.length,
            "Normal status code is 200",
            "Check console for more info and full response body"
        ].join("\r\n"));

        console.log(r.responseText, r);

    } });
```

**Extra Info:**

- The file name is in fact, `tex.txt`
- Jquery was loading before this
  line of code using **http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js**
- This is all being ran inside a **CLOUD IDE** called **Cloud9** at
  c9.io

**UPDATE:**  Console log showed three problems:

[blocked] The page at
   'https://c9.io/lemony_andrew/projectgray/workspace/index.html' was
   loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from
   'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js': this content should
   also be loaded over HTTPS.

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined main.js:4

Uncaught ReferenceError: loaded is not defined index.html:13

Comment: Try adding an error handler - perhaps something went wrong while loading the file.

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to. Check in the network tab to see if the txt file is being loaded.

Comment: Have a look at your browser's console during the request / response. That will reveal a lot to you.

Comment: I hate to have to ask, but you're sure that you've loaded jQuery, right?

Comment: Maybe your file name is `text.txt` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was more in depth than I could have thought.

For some reason I could not connect to the Jquery library by using an external link like so:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

I had to copy the code and paste it into a file on my server.

That solved the issue of jquery not being initialized. The next step was something I didn't even consider.

When working with javascript:

```
$.ajax({ url:"text.txt", complete:function(r){
```

I would have imagined that that line of code would load the file correctly. But in fact, I didn't know that when you are referencing a file in javascript `text.txt` that you have to include the path from the page calling the javascript. I have the actual text file located in:
`javascript/text.txt` because I thought the javascript loads files from the directory it's stored in...

Thanks all that helped!

Answer (score 1):

It's not certain whether the request actually happens.

You need to fire up the page in Chrome Inspector's Network tab and check the XHR sub-tab.

Alternatively, you can also try:

```
$.ajax({ url:"tex.txt", complete:function(r){

    alert([
        'Response Status code: ' + r.status,
        "Response Text length: " + r.responseText.length,
        "Normal status code is 200",
        "Check console for more info and full response body"
    ].join("\r\n"));

    console.log(r.responseText, r);

} });
```

Comment: Thanks for this block of code. It helped me find further errors after I solved the jquery problem.